# Fix PIL.ImageDraw.Draw.line with wide lines

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

From the PIL Documentation:

> **PIL.ImageDraw.Draw.line(xy, fill=None, width=0)**
>
> Draws a line between the coordinates in the xy list.
>
> Parameters:
>
> - xy – Sequence of either 2-tuples like [(x, y), (x, y), ...] or    numeric values like [x, y, x, y, ...].
> - fill – Color to use for the    line.
> - width – The line width, in pixels. **Note that line joins are not    handled well, so wide polylines will not look good.**

I'm looking for a fix for this issue. A good solution for me would be to have the line drawn by `PIL.ImageDraw` have rounded ends (`capstyle` in `TKinter`). Is there an equivalent in `PIL.ImageDraw`?

This is what I would like to obtain:
[image]

Minimal Working Example:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLUE = "#0000ff"
MyImage = Image.new('RGB', (600, 400), WHITE)
MyDraw = ImageDraw.Draw(MyImage)

MyDraw.line([100,100,150,200], width=40, fill=BLUE)
MyDraw.line([150,200,300,100], width=40, fill=BLUE)
MyDraw.line([300,100,500,300], width=40, fill=BLUE)

MyImage.show()
```

Result from MWE:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the same problem as you.  However, you can easily solve the problem by simply plotting a circle of the same diameter as the line widths at each vertex.  Below is your code, slightly modified, to fix the problem

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLUE = "#0000ff"
RED  = "#ff0000"
MyImage = Image.new('RGB', (600, 400), WHITE)
MyDraw = ImageDraw.Draw(MyImage)

# Note: Odd line widths work better for this algorithm,
# even though the effect might not be noticeable at larger line widths

LineWidth = 41

MyDraw.line([100,100,150,200], width=LineWidth, fill=BLUE)
MyDraw.line([150,200,300,100], width=LineWidth, fill=BLUE)
MyDraw.line([300,100,500,300], width=LineWidth, fill=BLUE)

Offset = (LineWidth-1)/2

# I have plotted the connecting circles in red, to show them better
# Even though they look smaller than they should be, they are not.
# Look at the diameter of the circle and the diameter of the lines -
# they are the same!

MyDraw.ellipse ((150-Offset,200-Offset,150+Offset,200+Offset), fill=RED)
MyDraw.ellipse ((300-Offset,100-Offset,300+Offset,100+Offset), fill=RED)

MyImage.show()
```

[image: Lines with rounded ends]

Comment: A very nice answer, but downvoted because dmitry_romanov's answer should replace it.

Answer (score 12):

There are standard option `joint='curve'` of the [ImageDraw.line](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageDraw.html#PIL.ImageDraw.PIL.ImageDraw.ImageDraw.line) designed to fix it.

Your example may look like

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLUE = "#0000ff"
MyImage = Image.new('RGB', (600, 400), WHITE)
MyDraw = ImageDraw.Draw(MyImage)

line_points = [(100, 100), (150, 200), (300, 100), (500, 300)]
MyDraw.line(line_points, width=40, fill=BLUE, joint='curve')

MyImage.show()
```

Special care is required to address the end-points, but joints are fixed.

The result:

[image: Fixed line with joint='curve']

Comment: Make sure your coordinates are formatted exactly as above [(x,y),....]. line is kind of flexible with other formats (unrolled list, numpy, etc.), but these will cause headaches with "joint".

Comment: Hmm, doesn't work for me, whatever I do. Throws `TypeError: line() got an unexpected keyword argument 'joint'` :-(

Comment: According to the manual the keyword should be there: https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/releasenotes/5.3.0.html#curved-joints-for-line-sequences

Comment: Note: If you are drawing a polygon (out of lines), the point where the last line joins the first will not get this curve treatment. Extend the polygon so it draws all the way around and then retraces the last line, to get it looking nice.